# is there a term for databases which are not system databases?

Tags: sql-server

Is there a term for all databases in SQL Server that are **not** system databases (such as `master`, `model`, `tempdb`)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"[User Databases](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms345483.aspx)".

The same "System" vs "User" distinction is also made for other objects such as tables.

[For example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms189121.aspx)

> Members of the db_datareader fixed database role can read all data
>   from all *user* tables.

`msdb` and the distribution database (if you use replication) are also system databases that you do not mention by the way.